# How to check what table a value is in with a CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to tables A and B and in both tables the column `ID`.

And I am looking how to show which tables an ID is in.

For example:

Table A

```
ID:31101534
ID:31101535
ID:31101536
```

Table B

```
ID:31101533
ID:31101535
ID:31101530
```

I tried to do this with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
  case 
      when A.ID = B.ID then 'Both'
      when A.ID != B.ID and A.ID is null then 'Table B'
      when A.ID != B.ID and B.ID is null then 'Table A'
      else ' '
  end as TEST
```

Comment: FYI, it's a `CASE` *expression*; it returns a scalar value. T-SQL doesn't `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: `A.ID != B.ID and A.ID is null` can never be true. If `A.ID` has the value `NULL`  then `A.ID != B.ID` will return UNKNOWN. *Nothing* is equal nor *not* equal to `NULL`, *including* `NULL`. The only way to compare to a `NULL` is with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Like Larnu said I did change with IS NULL and IS NOT NULL and now it is working corretly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a full outer join here:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.ID, b.ID) AS ID,
    CASE WHEN a.ID IS NOT NULL AND b.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Both'
         WHEN a.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Table A'
         ELSE 'Table B' END AS status
FROM TableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.ID = a.ID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link above]

### Demo